# Is it good to use pyqtgraph for real time application?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

I need a clarification regarding the usage of `pyqtgraph`. Can I  use `pyqtgraph` for a real-time application or should I use `matplotlib`? which would be better for an application which needs millisecond accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it, if the number of samples is not very high (e.g. 10 kS/second approximately).

The reason for this is that pyqtgraph doesn't use OpenGL (See: [Improving Performance of pyqtgraph real-time plotting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/TzQxdhYMvv0/N1-lCYSkEwAJ)).

As for "millisecond accuracy": this depends on what you mean by that. Python is not hard real-time, so updating with 1ms hard real-time intervals is not possible.

Comment: It's a good answer but it lacks references. No +1 for now